# Is the difference between key and scales just unordered vs. ordered pitches?

Tags: scales, key

Hi guys I was trying to understand the relationship between keys and scales, from what I understood starting from the basic pitch:
A A# B C C# D D# E F F# G G#

if we start from one and take WWHWWWH

we obtain a major scale if instead we do WHWWHW we obtain a Minor scale.

and so far I understand, now from what I understand a key is simply an unordered set of pitch.
instead a scale is an ordered set of pitches.

so for example
CDEFGABC is the c major scale instead ABCDEFGA is the A minor scale and they contain the same notes, so they shouldn't be in the same key? so should Cmajor key and A minor key be the same?

and in this way I started from the scale and I said since I take the notes of this scale ( for example a C major) i have a C major Key, so to get a key I always have to start from the scale?

Answer (score 0):

It's more the other way round. Any *scale* is an ordered set of notes which (usually) goes together. True, start anywhere on the whole set (chromatic), and count TTSTTTS (or WWHWWWH), and you end up with a major scale, in the key of whatever note you started/finished on.

Similarly with a minor scale - but only the *natural* minor, which, if you didn't realise, is the same order, just starting on the 6th note of any major scale.

A key, however is a slightly different concept, as you suspect. Any key will have (and have to have) a *root* note - which is the note where any tune in that key feels most at rest - home. Properly know as its **tonal centre**. Your examples of CDEFGAB could actually have seven different notes as the root, or home note, of a key - or *mode*. The most common key names will be C major or A minor, but could just as well be D Dorian or F Lydian, for example.

The other aspect of a key is which notes it contains. They're called *diatonic*, and 'belong' to a particular key. Let's take the scale notes of, say, G A B C D E F♯. They all 'belong' to key G major, and when put together in ascending/descending order, constitute the scale of G major.

You find that any set of notes, such as this, are **in** a key, and so key and scale are related, but not synonymous.